# Need to see if all Critical Updates are installed on a Windows Server in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, windows-update

I have a requirement where I need to check Remote Servers to see if all of their Critical updates are installed and then return PASS or FAIL.

Is there a way with WMI for me to do this with VBScript?

EDIT:

I did find this
[Windows Update Check with vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179914/windows-update-check-with-vbscript) but it only works on the local machine and not remote.

Answer (score 0):

This link with UpdateHF_v2.6a.vbs by Rob Dunn is made to work with all versions of Windows. It's made with VBS to use WMI, and works on local and remote hosts.. I've been using 2.5a for years. There is no changelog, though Rob is updating the script in response to feedback.

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/82-windows-update-agent-force-script-email-results-version-2-6

If you need "wrappers" to do this in bulk using a list of computers and psexec to run it, let me know. :)