# Checking with VBScript if server has all critical updates installed -- managed by WSUS

Tags: vbscript, windows-update

I am developing a script that gets deployed and executed on a server (so it is as if I am running it locally and not remote).

I need to check to see if all critical updates are installed. Each server has a WSUS server managing its updates. Is there a way for me to do this with VBScript.

I was looking at this post,
[Windows Update Check with vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179914/windows-update-check-with-vbscript)

but I don't know if it will help me since I'm not too familiar with how windows update works, but I only need critical updates.

If I follow the method that the selected answer in the post I linked, will

`CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")`

work if WSUS is managing updates? What do I use to only grab updates that WSUS deems critical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Update.Session` object will query whatever update server a host is pointed towards, be it Microsoft's servers or a local WSUS. It reports only approved updates that apply to the host.

Comment: Great news! Do you know if the link I posted, or any other way to only query "Critical Updates"?

Comment: The search string `IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'` should return only critical updates.